# Neural Networks training and testing in R

Tags: r

I am using r for a neural networks problem. Here is my coding:

```
library(nnet)
set.seed(1)
ann<-nnet(traindata[,1]~traindata[,2]+traindata[,3]+traindata[,4]+traindata[,5]+traindata[,6]+traindata[,7]+traindata[,8],size=10,decay=0.001,maxit=10000)
pred0<-predict(ann,traindata[,1])
pred1<-predict(ann,testdata)
nmse0 <- mean((traindata$RTDP-pred0)^2)/mean((traindata$RTDP-mean(traindata$RTDP))^2)
nmse1 <- mean((traindata$RTDP-pred1)^2)/mean((traindata$RTDP-mean(traindata$RTDP))^2)
```

However, it says that the number of rows in testdata doesn't match number of rows in traindata, what's this problem?

Comment: Do not use `[` (or `$`) in your model formulas.

Comment: As @joran said, the function `predict` is looking to match the names of the model `ann` to the new data `testdata`. When you created `ann` you didn't tell it names to use, only column numbers. `predict` won't match column numbers.

Comment: The corollary to "don't use extraction operators in formulas" is that you _do_ need to use a data argument so that there is an appropriate environment in which the formula can be evaluated.